# Print error in c lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand

Tags: c++, c

I am having code error while compiling this

```
#include <stdio.h>      // standard input / output functions
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>     // string function definitions
#include <unistd.h>     // UNIX standard function definitions
#include <fcntl.h>      // File control definitions
#include <errno.h>      // Error number definitions
#include <termios.h>   

void main()
{
int USB = open( "/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR| O_NOCTTY );         
struct termios tty;
struct termios tty_old;
memset (&tty, 0, sizeof tty);
/* Error Handling */
if ( tcgetattr ( USB, &tty ) != 0 ) 
{
printf("Error %d form tcgetattr : %d /n",&errno,strerror(errno));
}
}
```

Error is

```
USB2UART.c:18:49: error:lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand
printf("Error %d form tcgetattr : %d /n",&errno,&strerror(errno));
                                         ^
```

I am using USB to UART conversion and trying to get error with its handler.
Hope someone could help. Thanks :)

Comment: How is errno declared?

Comment: So what is the declaration of errno?

Comment: actually it is working correctly with C++

    std::cout << "Error " << errno << " from tcgetattr: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just don't need the & operator.

```
if ( tcgetattr ( USB, &tty ) != 0 ) {
    printf( "Error %d form tcgetattr : %s /n", errno, strerror( errno ) );
}
```

try this

Comment: Thank you for quick reply but still it is giving error
 
USB2UART.c: In function ‘main’:
USB2UART.c:18:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘char *’ [-Wformat=]
     printf( "Error %d form tcgetattr : %d /n", errno, strerror( errno ) );

Comment: The second `%d` has to be `%s`.

Comment: fixed it. please try again and let me know if it works

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that you are trying to apply `&` at a literal whereas it is applied on  a variable and not a literal. Try to remove `&` and then give it a try.

The C++ standard, §5.3.1,3 says:

> The result of the unary & operator is a pointer to its operand. The
>   operand shall be an lvalue [...]

Comment: Removing it gives me this type of error

 In function ‘main’:
USB2UART.c:18:1: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
 printf("Error %d form tcgetattr : %d /n",&errno,strerror(errno));
 ^
USB2UART.c:18:1: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘char *’ [-Wformat=]

Comment: Maybe you should mention which standard you're quoting, especially since this is one of those two-language questions.

Comment: @juanchopanza:- Thanks. Updated that!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're passing an `int` pointer to `printf` for the second and third parameters while it expects an actual `int`. A lot of people get confused with it at first because `scanf` requires a pointer but `printf` doesn't.

So, just remove the `&` before both `errno` and `strerror(errno)` and it should be fine. Like this:

```
printf("Error %i form tcgetattr : %s \n", errno, strerror(errno));
```

PS: Also notice I fixed your new-line escape character. It was `/n` white the correct is `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

`errno`, as defined in the C library, is an int used to report errors.

`strerror`, in the other hand, is used to get a c string (char *) from the value of errno.

The %d flag of `printf` needs an `int`, and `&errno` is an `int *`. Replace it by `errno`

Also, in order to print a `char *` with `printf`, you have to use %s, and not %d.

So just replace by this :

```
printf("Error %d from tcgetattr : %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
```

By the way, you should use [perror](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/perror/) in order to log erros, because it logs errors on stderr.

Using perror, it will look like this :

```
perror("Error from tcgetattr");
```